# paginate_links() with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have a custom taxonomy that is pulling in a list of posts assosciated with it. Previously - in the `$posts_args` array, I set the `post_per_page` option to `-1` but realized pagination should be added to do the large amount of media that will be present with each post. I read over [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) (and added their example in my query below), but have not had any luck thus-far parsing out the posts as needed. Right now - `posts_per_page` is set to `2` in the general `WordPress > Reading` settings (which works - only 2 posts are shown on the page) and the `paginate_links()` function call does in-fact generate the amount of pages needed based on the posts per page and the total number of posts, but when I do go to the secondary pages (like /page/2) the same posts are shown that are on the first page. Any suggestions on what I may be missing? Thanks!

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'moulding_profiles',
    'meta_key' => '_mouldings_dimensions_height',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxfunc_tax_name,
                'field' => 'id',
                'include_children' => 0,
                'terms' => $term_id
            )
        )
);
$posts_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
$i = 0; // count
$total_items = $posts_query->post_count; // total profiles
$number_columns = $mouldings_options['profile_item_columns']; // number of columns
if ($posts_query->have_posts() ) {

    // Filter function
    mouldings_profile_list_before();

    echo '<div id="mouldings-list">';
    while($posts_query->have_posts() && ($i < $total_items)) { ?>
        <?php $posts_query->the_post(); if ($i % $number_columns == 0) echo ($i > 0 ? '</div><div class="row">' : '<div class="row first-row">'); ?>
        <div class="<?php echo 'width'.intval(100 / $number_columns); ?> <?php if ($i % $number_columns == 0) echo 'first-item'; ?>">
            <?php
                moulding_profile_teaser($profile_ID = get_the_ID());
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    mouldings_profile_list_after();

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $posts_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was missing `'paged' => get_query_var('paged')` in the initial query.